# Is there a way to use asterix in Sitecore SOLR configuration root?

Tags: solr, sitecore8.1

First of all a little context.

I'm using Sitecore 8.1 with Solr 5.5.0-1 and my data are stored like this :

```
sitecore  
->content  
-->Assistance  
--->Products  
---->Alarms  
----->Themes  
------>Theme1  
------->Questions  
---->Interruptors  
----->Themes  
------>Theme1  
------->Questions  
---->...
```

Is there a way I can set the root of my crawler like so to index the themes and questions ?

```
<Root>/sitecore/content/Assistance/Produits/*/Themes</Root>
```

The real problem is that if my client add a new type of product the index will not search at all in it.

Comment: Please move your question to dedicated sitecore forum sitecore.stackexchange.com

Comment: Done : https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6651/is-there-a-way-to-use-asterix-in-sitecore-solr-configuration-root